# I have a problem in submitting comments to server using json and fetch in django

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, web

I am working on a bookstore project using django and javascript. I want to allow user to add comments on each book and send the comment without reloading the page using JSON

html:

```
<h3 id="authorname">{{book.authorname}}</h3>
<h1 id="bookname"> {{book.name}}</h1>
<p id="slogan">-{{book.slogan}}-</p>
<h2 id="price">Price:- <span>${{book.price}}</span></h2>

    <form id="addcomment">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input hidden name='thecommentuser' value="{{ request.user.id }}" id="commentsubmitter">
        <input hidden name='thecommentbook' value="{{ book.id }}" id="commentbook">
        <textarea  name='thecomment'id="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

script:

```
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

document.querySelector('#addcomment').onsubmit = function() {
  fetch('/comments', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
        thecomment: document.querySelector('#comment').value,
        thecommentuser: document.querySelector('#commentsubmitter').value,
        thecommentbook: document.querySelector('#commentbook').value,
    })})}});
```

models.py:

```
class books(models.Model):
    bookuser= models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default= None, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, 
    price = models.IntegerField()
    authorname= models.CharField(max_length=30)


class comments(models.Model): 
    comment =  models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    commentuser = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    commentbook = models.ForeignKey('books', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'thecomment': self.comment,
            'thecommentuser': self.commentuser,
            'thecommentbook': self.commentbook
        }
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book/<int:id>', views.book, name='book'),
    path('comments', views.addcomments, name='comments')
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import json

def book(request, id):
    submitedbook = books.objects.get(id=id)
    bkchapters = chapters.objects.filter(chapterbook=submitedbook)
    bkrewards = rewards.objects.filter(rewardbook = submitedbook)
    return render(request, 'network/book.html', {'book':submitedbook, 'chapters':bkchapters, 'rewards':bkrewards})

@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def addcomments(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('posted')
        data= json.loads(request.body)
        comment = data.get('thecomment', '')
        commentuser = data.get('thecommentuser')
        commentbook = data.get('thecommentbook', '')
            
        cuser = User.objects.get(id = commentuser)
        cbook = books.objects.get(id = commentbook)
        thecommentt = comments(
            thecomment=comment,
            thecommentuser=cuser, 
            thecommentbook=cbook
        )
        thecommentt.save()
```

when I open the comments in the admin page I don't find any submitted data and the page reload upon submitting a comment. the order of `print('posted')` in views.py isn't displayed to me upon adding a comment and that means that the request isn't sent but I don't know why

this appears to me in the terminal window upon adding the comment:

```
[30/Oct/2022 01:47:19] "GET /book/1?csrfmiddlewaretoken=9QgGiDOUnVxMlxZQ6UkSmiO4auq5BLojV6iWW55qE9LER929Qj7WB8LVtkBfpnJ4&thecommentuser=1&thecommentbook=1&thecomment=Book HTTP/1.1" 200 14927
```

I tried to delete `if request.method == 'POST':` in views and to print in views but nothing changed. Also I tried to `console.log('submitted')` on submitting the comment but nothing appeared

new update:

I find that the error comes from the browser itself as I find that data is sent upon submitting from another browser so although the two browsers are updated. so how could I solve this?

Comment: can you please put traceback of the error also?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have edited the code to provide all the needed

Comment: @DivyaPrakash Is the last code I have edited is the traceback that use need ?

Comment: I mean to say what error are you getting when you are submitting comments?